# Spring Webflow and Inheritance

Tags: java, spring, serialization, spring-webflow

I came upon one issue in Spring WebFlow. I have a class A that extends class B. class B looks like this:

```
public class B{
    private Collection<Class<?>> hints = new ArrayList<>();
    public B(){}
    public B(Collection<Class<?>> hints){ this.hints=hints; }

    //getter and setter for hints
}
```

Class A is a form, has some Strings/Integers as private fields. Class A extends class B and implements Serializable. During execution of WebFlow it stores object in problably `some sort of the map` and re-prodcues form that is instace of A. Sadly it doesn't reproduce class B. After every re-production `hints` from class B are empty collection. Can you explain me why is that and what should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think that I posted it to quickly. Implementing `Serializable` in class B does the trick. But why? What diffrence for `Spring WebFlow` implementing `Serializable` makes?